# What are the upgrades of the bloonchipper?

Tags: bloons-monkey-city

So I have just got the bloonchipper which sucks in bloons and shreds them but I need to know whether it is worth spending a bunch of money to build bloonchipper's building to get its upgrades or should I spend my money on other stuff. What are bloonchipper's upgrades?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118178/discussion-between-melon-pult-and-eris-the-guest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out.

> First path: suckier, heavy duty suck, dual layer blades, and super wide funnel.

> Second path: longer range suck, faster shred, triple barrel, and supa vac.